# how to pass command line string arguments and compare them python

Tags: python, string

i want to comapre two strings by passing one string from command prompt, this is sample code, when I pass `c://python sample.py x`, it is storing x1 as x1=[' x '] now if I compare `sys.argv[1:]` with string 'x' its false, may be its comparing `[' x '] == 'x'`, how should I remove that square brackets and single quotes around my input after it reads

`import sys`
`print sys.argv[1:]`
`x1=sys.argv[1:]`
`print x1`

`if x1=='x':`
    `print "true"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare a list with a string here.

Do

```
x1 = sys.argv[1]
```

instead of

```
x1 = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: how to pass couple of words as one string like `python sample.py Targus Notepac Laptop Bag` here i want to pass Targus Notepac Laptop Bag to `x1`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sys.argv[1:]` you get a list slice, which in turn is a list even if it contains a single item. What you need to do is to index the item you want:

```
sys.argv[1]
```

If you don't know the number of arguments:

```
for x in sys.argv[1:]:
    if x == 'x':
        print x
        break
```